# Use of zeromq@6.0.0-beta.16 package for a web server (undefined symbol: sodium_init)

Tags: node.js, node-modules, zeromq, failed-installation, libsodium

I am running RHEL9 with node v20.1.0.
Zeromq installs without problems, but when I run the command:
`npm start`
an error occurs:
`node: symbol lookup error: /home/fcampion/COMINT/comint-stub/node_modules/zeromq/build/Release/zeromq.node: undefined symbol: sodium_init`

Rebuilding with:
`npm rebuild`
brings up the same error.

What should I do, why does this error apperar? Thanks in advance

I tried installing libsodium in the system but nothing changes.
I also tried 3 solutions from the internet (there is few content) but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found upgrading Node to version 18.16.0 ( previously 14.17.0 ) and running 'npm i zeromq@5' fixed this issue.

Comment: Using zeromq@5 fixes everything, but my colleagues were using zeromq@6. I fixed dockerizing the project and using it from the container